# CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout not displaying the large toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a child activity that I wanted to display a large toolbar with an image using Parallax effect, however, if I use Fresco SimpleDraweeView (URI set in runtime) it doesn't work as expected.

[image: Preview]

If I use an ImageView it shows the image but the scrolling and parallax doesn't work.

What am I missing in my code?

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.app.ui.BookActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_book"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AppBar Include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.BookActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProfile"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/hq_item_background"
            fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_book" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content Include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/light_background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".ui.ComicBookActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_book"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

I was closing `android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` tag before the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` tag. Now I'm having a different problem of the status bar not becoming transparent when I scroll, but that's a problem for a new question on StackOverflow.